# regular expression convert version wrong

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hey Community I have an issue I am using a regular expression on and instead of getting the full version I am getting the following _3 where I am supposed to get 13_3

This is how I am using the expression -

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148";
$pattern = '/os ([0-9]?.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])*/';
preg_match($pattern,strtolower($useragent),$m);
```

This is how I use it for Android -

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; moto e5 play Build/OPGS28.54-53-8-11; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Mobile Safari/537.36";
$pattern = '/android ((\d+|\.).[^ ,);]+)/';
preg_match($pattern,strtolower($useragent),$m);
```

I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Maybe `preg_match('/os ([0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+)?)/i', $useragent, $m)`?

Comment: yes but this won't work for 13_3_3 for example

Comment: Mat, I fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you are not accounting for the possible underscore.

This part `[0-9]?.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]` matches an optional digit, any char except a newline followed by 3 optional digits and a digit which might also match for example `x1`

You get the value `_13` because you are repeating the capturing itself, capturing the value of the last iteration.

As an alternative you could also make use of `\K` to clear the match buffer and get the match only.

```
\bos\h+\K\d+(?:_\d+)*\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `os` Match literally
- `\h+\K` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, then forget what was matched
- `\d+(?:_\d+)*` Match 1+ digit optionally repeated by _ and 1+ digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U9VhTV/1/)

For example

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148";
$pattern = '/\bos\h+\K\d+(?:_\d+)*\b/';
preg_match($pattern,strtolower($useragent),$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Output

```
13_3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
preg_match('/os\s+([0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+)*)/i', $useragent, $m)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH1i4d/1/).

- `os` - a string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:_[0-9]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of `_` and 1+ digits.

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/6eGYi):

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148";
if (preg_match('/os\s+([0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+)*)/i', $useragent, $m)) {
   print_r($m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match('/os ([0-9].(?:_?[0-9]+)+)*/gi',$useragent,$m);`

this will be the code then:

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_33 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148";
if (preg_match('/os ([0-9].(?:_?[0-9]+)+)*/', $useragent, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

output in group 1:
`13_3_33`